# How to use TimedUndoAdapter in ListViewAnimations

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, shared-libraries

i use this animated list view [ListViewAnimations](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#getting-started) in an application, and all work fine....

```
`SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter swipeUndoAdapter = new SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter(myAdapter,getActivity(),
            new OnDismissCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(@NonNull final ViewGroup listView, @NonNull final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        myAdapter.remove(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        swipeUndoAdapter.setAbsListView(mDynamicListView);
        AlphaInAnimationAdapter animAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(swipeUndoAdapter);
        animAdapter.setAbsListView(mDynamicListView);
        animAdapter.getViewAnimator().setInitialDelayMillis(INITIAL_DELAY_MILLIS );
        mDynamicListView.setAdapter(animAdapter);
        mDynamicListView.enableSimpleSwipeUndo();
        mDynamicListView.enableDragAndDrop();
        mDynamicListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                               final int position, final long id) {
                    mDynamicListView.startDragging(position);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
```

but if I try to replace SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter with `TimedUndoAdapter` I have the following problem: (I need to use TimedUndoAdapter because because i need it erase itself after some time)

```
Bound mismatch: The generic constructor TimedUndoAdapter(V, Context, OnDismissCallback) of type TimedUndoAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayAdapter<String>, Activity, new OnDismissCallback(){}). The inferred type ArrayAdapter<String> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends BaseAdapter & UndoAdapter>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does your `myAdapter` implement the [`UndoAdapter`](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/lib-manipulation/src/main/java/com/nhaarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/swipedismiss/undo/UndoAdapter.java) interface?

Comment: Yes , in fact, the code with the class SimpleSwipeUndoAdapter works perfectly .

Comment: I try to find the piece of code when you use the TimedUndoAdapter in your [example](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/tree/master/example) but i didn't succeed ....can you link me the class where you use it ? thank in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the declaration of myAdapter. I ran into the same problem. Used to have a declaration like: ArrayAdapter. Changing the declaration to the Adapter class i defined (in my case MyListAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter and implements UndoAdapter) solved the problem for me.